# Visual Studio : build not referenced plugin project

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, build, reference, dependencies

I'm working on a WPF application that loads plugin assemblies on runtime.

My solution contains the host app (wpf app set as startup project) and the plugin as another project (class library).
The plugin project references the host app.

My problem is that since the host app doesn't reference the plugin project, the plugin project is not built when I click "Start" and I need to manually build it each time I modify it before I start the host app.

In the "Project dependencies" of my solution, I cannot add my plugin project to the dependencies of my host app since VS says it would create a circular reference (it wouldn't since my host app doesn't really need the plugin to compile or work).

Is there a way to tell VS I want the plugin project built when I click Start (if the plugin project is out of date), even if it's not a real reference ?

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: I'm having pretty much the same issue. Did you find a way to achieve this?